# Werid spacing to the left inside of DIV help!

Tags: css, html, spacing

For some reason theres a space to the left inside of the div

heres a picture of what i'm seeing http://tinypic.com/r/msc2h/7

CSS

```
 div {margin:auto;}

    li{padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: inline; float:left;}

    ul{height: 20px; text-align: left; vertical-align: center; margin: auto;}
```

HTML

```
<div style="border: 1px solid white; width: 500px;">
    <ul>
    <li>Home&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Product&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Links&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Contact Us&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Abuot Us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not from the `div`, it's from the padding/margin that your browser sets for you if you don't override it. Try this:

```
    div {
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid white;
        width: 500px;
    }

    li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 5px;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }

    ul {
        height: 20px;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

I've noticed that you were using `&nbsp;` to add spaces between your list items, that's just plain messy and redundant, so I've added `margin: 0 5px;` for each list item.

So erase all those `&nbsp;` and move the border and width properties to the CSS, which I've done above since it's good practice.

```
    <div>
        <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Product</li>
        <li>Links</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
        <li>About US</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

To learn more why it's a good practice to separate structure (HTML) and presentation (CSS) watch these great videos from Google: [HTML, CSS, and Javascript from the Ground Up](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/).

Comment: i just added that spacing real qwik to post it up. but thanks that did it. LOL

Answer (score 2):

You should have padding/margin set to 0 for UL as well. Ul has padding by itself.

Comment: This actually depends on the user agent's default styles. Some browsers use margin, some use padding; some apply the styles to the `<li>`, some to the containing list.

Comment: User this one for UL: ul{height: 20px; text-align: left; vertical-align: center; margin: 0px; padding:0px}

Answer (score 0):

It might be that margin:auto on the ul, which will basically center the ul in the div. With this kind of list that can behave unexpectedly.

Are you using developer tools like firebug or chrome's built in "Inspect element" tool to take a closer look? They will highlight each individual element by itself and tell you exactly what values are being used for margin/padding/everything. It can really speed up this kind of problem solving. Another easy way to see what's going on is to give everything a 1px border of a different color. That way you can better tell if the problem is inside or outside the ul, or even somehow on one of the li.